# Different request code on activity result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I calling new activity for result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and `SPEECH_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE` is defined the following way:

```
public static final int SPEECH_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 4;
```

but on result I'm getting different value:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //requestCode == 196608 + SPEECH_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE
    ...
}
```

I tried with different values for `SPEECH_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE`.

I'm using `android.support.v4`.

Comment: What value are you receiving for resultCode in onActivityResult?  Your text is not clear.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I'm getting result, i.e. RESULT_OK. How does it matter? I'm getting different `reqestCode` to one I'm providing in `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: The `resultCode` and `data` (Intent) are the result coming from the `Activity` you started.  Since `RecognizerIntent` doesn't specify the values for `requestCode`, they are likely implementation specific and not critical.

Comment: You're welcolme. Is there a cleaner way to mark this question as duplicate ?

Comment: @PierreRust I have no idea. I marked it as duplicate.